# Orthogonal matrix problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, linear-transformations, orthogonality

So the question asks: Let $A$ and $B$ be n×nn×n orthogonal matrices, with $n≥2$. Which of the following matrices must be orthogonal?

A. $A^TB$

B. The matrix C obtained by multiplying the second column of $A$ by 3.

C. The matrix C obtained by switching the first two columns of $A$.

D. The matrix C obtained by adding the first column of $A$ to the second column of $A$.

E. $(AB)^{-1}$

F. $A+B$

So so far I got:

Since the product $AB$ of two orthogonal matrices is orthogonal, and the inverse of an orthogonal matrix is orthogonal. So E is right.

F does not have to be orthogonal. For example $I_2+I_2=2I_2$ which is not orthogonal.

Also, since $A^T=A^{-1}$ is an orthogonal matrix, then A is true.

But I have no idea anout B,C,D. I think C should be right because it does not change the number of the matrix. But is this true? And are B and D right and why?

Comment: Do you know the fact that a matrix is orthogonal iff the columns form an orthogonal basis (usual scalar product)? If not, try to prove it. You can answer B, C, and D using this fact.

Comment: For B and D, consider what happens when $A = I$.

Comment: you might want to break this problem up